# gnuplot map with pm3d, isolines and labels

Tags: gnuplot, contour

In Gnuplot 5.0.1, I've tried without success to plot a map (with pm3d), including isolines and labels with numerical value of each isoline. It seems that I can obtain only isoline OR labels with isovalues.

```
set terminal qt  font ",14"
unset surface
set title "OASPL [dB]" font ",18"
se xra[-15.401199999999999:14.497400000000001]
set xlabel "x [m]" font ",18"
set ylabel "y [m]" font ",18"
set cbrange[85:115]
set cbtics 85,3,115
set style data pm3d
set style function pm3d
set pm3d implicit at b
set palette negative grey maxcolor 10
set view map scale 1
set pm3d interpolate 10,10
set contour base
set cntrlabel onecolor format '%8.3g' font ',6' start 80 interval 20
set cntrparam levels increment 85,3,115
set style fill   solid 1.00 border lt -1
set style textbox opaque margins  1.0,  1.0 border 
spl 'OASPL-tec-carpet_03b180.dat' u 1:2:4 w l lw 1.3 lt -1 t ''
repl 'OASPL-tec-carpet_03b180.dat' u 1:2:4 w labels t ''
```

what I obtain is this (after the 'spl....')

[image: with labels]

or this (after the 'repl...')

[image: with labels]

There is a way to obtain both lines and labels?

[Data file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzxiku2vby263r1/OASPL-tec-carpet_03b180.dathttps://www.dropbox.com/s/uzxiku2vby263r1/OASPL-tec-carpet_03b180.dat?dl=0)

Comment: Can you provide your data?  It is difficult to see what is going wrong without being able to run your example.

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing this but I can confirm that I am seeing the same.  I tried plotting both separately using `set multiplot layout 1,1` where they would superimpose over each other, and I see the same thing happen.  In either case, I don't think that it should happen.  I am suspicious that you may have found a bug.  Unless somebody comes along with a better answer explaining that this is correct behavior, you may want to report this on gnuplot's bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure ,but you can test this command:

spl 'OASPL-tec-carpet_03b180.dat' u 1:2:4 w l lw 1.3 lt -1 t '',
'OASPL-tec-carpet_03b180.dat' u 1:2:4 w labels t ''

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).